# Rhombus in layers tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there an way to plot something like

[image]

with tikz? (I mean other than carefully drawing each rhombus so that they do not intersect).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can install an orthographic projection with the `perspective` library, and project on the xy planes with the `3d` library. The distance between the planes can be controlled by adjusting the view angles, and introducing a prefactor for `\Z` in `canvas is xy plane at z=-\Z`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={20}{12}]
\foreach \Z in {0,...,4}
{\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=-\Z,transform shape]
 \ifnum\Z>0
 \draw (0,0) grid[step={pow(2,2-\Z)}] (4,4);
 \fi
 \draw[semithick,red] (0,0) coordinate(p\Z) rectangle (4,4);
\end{scope}
\path (p\Z) node[left]{$\mathcal{D}_{\Z}(Q)$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]